# nlog: log on the same line

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

Is there a way to make `nlog` log stuff on the same line and only if the string that is being logged contains the new line character (`\r\n`), only then to jump on a new line?

I've seen something like

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop-1);
```

but I prefer to do this from the configuration layout if it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace newlines with something else by using the Replace [NewLines Layout Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-NewLines-Layout-Renderer) but that might replace all newlines.

You can also try the [LineEndingMode](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_LineEndingMode.htm) and set it to none.  This might still process inline newlines when inserted but not insert one at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the NLog-delegate `LogMessageGenerator`:

```
_logger.Info(() => { Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop-1); return "test" });
```

But if having multiple targets and only one of them is a console, then it might not work that well.